# Axis Mapping gives one-sided values

Tags: movement, unreal

this has got me stuck badly: my project is in 2.5D. Jumping and crouching not implemented yet.

Making use of Axis Mapping Input from the project settings, where numpad 4= 1 and numpad 6= -1 to control my movement, the follow problem poses itself:

I have a blendspace with a horizontal axis which is MovementDirection from -1 to 1 divided in 2.The upward axis is a MovementSpeed from 0 to = 200 = Max Walk Speed on my CharacterMovement asset.

In this Blendspace I go from idle in the bottom middle, to WalkForward and WalkBackward in the upper outer extremes.

However, when in my Level Blueprint I get my MovementSpeed and MovementDirection variables from my "BP_Player" Anim Instance, in order to print them, I can see that my MovementSpeed goes all the way to my max which is 200, while in the other direction it's stuck around 0,01.

I thought it would go -200 but it doesn't, which is messing up my WalkForward blendspace part, only blending very slightly into it.

However in the blendspace I have positioned my WalkForward and WalkBackward animations correctly.

Any idea where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: What happens if you print to screen the Axis variable?  Is this working correctly?

Comment: I made a mistake, I was printing my MovementDirection. Not my MovementSpeed. The speed is completely correct. The direction is bad. It should go from -1 to 0 to 1 (basic mistake). Instead it goes from -200 to 0.01.
This is what causing my blendspace to work from one side only.